# Toilet makes screeching/chirping sound when anyone in my building used water

Tags: toilet

Like the title says, when anyone in my building uses water, my toilet makes a really loud screeching/chirping sound. I've found that by pushing down on the black arm, the noise stops, but when the arm comes back up, the noise starts again.

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this and/or how to keep the arm from coming all the way up?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just replace that valve (and probably the flapper too). They are cheap enough and from your description it can't be working right. Make sure it is installed and adjusted per specification, and you should be all set.

Firstly, you don't want it held down, holding it down is what is true when the tank is not full and therefore, it will open the fill valve to fill the tank. This means water running. You don't want water running 24/7 in your toilet, this is bad.

Now, when it is all the way up, it should not be running at all, but since (when water is being used in your building), the change in water pressure **APPARENTLY** is enough to starve that valve, just enough it squeals. At least this makes the most sense for what you've described.

Now, the reason why I noted to replace the valve seat is because the water may be trickling out just enough that the fill is barely on. This coupled with water pressure change......

Also... I'd be curious what size pipes are the water supply side to the things in the building. There really shouldn't be a big pressure change when one other thing is in use and your toilet (supplied by 3/8) shouldn't see a drop. But it does. (based on your description).

Comment: thanks for getting back to me. Anddd assuming that I know very little to nothing about plumbing or this kind of repair... Do you have any resource or hows to that can lead me through this?

Comment: I will say it is fairly easy. You can always hire a plumber or report the running water condition to your building management and they will replace it. Otherwise, the kit is less than $20 USDat most big box stores and comes with instructions and pictures. Feel free to ask away if it is confusing.

Comment: Haha. So, I feel silly for even thinking this would be a difficult install by any means. I stopped by Lowe's and got a fill valve/flapper kit and since I got the same brand of the one I currently had, I literally only had to take off the top part of the fill valve, then connect the hose back to it and the overflow valve. Then snap on the flapper. That was super easy and now the problem is fixed. No more annoying sounds!

But thank you SOOOO much for your comment because otherwise, I wouldn't have even though about doing this myself and would've instead waited on my landlord.

Comment: Generally, the fill valve is replace as an entire unit. Also, generally, most landlords want to know about failures in their apartments. But either way, I'm glad you found out it is indeed easy & was no sweat, awesome! (Probably advisable to notify the landlord that you repaired it, but that's just gp's (good practices))

Comment: Haha thanks for the advice. I actually did notify the landlord of the issue the day before I posted on here. He responded and asked for further details and said he would get his plumber out soon. But then I told him that I fixed it and he said great and to take the amount for the part off of rent lol. So everything worked out fine. Thanks again!